# can i resign an ipa with the certificate and embedded.mobileprovision only without the private key?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, x509certificate, ipa

I have extracted an enterprise distribution certificate from the mobileprovision file from an  ipa but could not get the private key 
So can i resign an another ipa with the certificate and embedded.mobileprovision only without the private key?
And if yes how to do this ?

Comment: I would dearly hope not.

Comment: No.  That would defeat the purpose of signing. You must have the private key.

Comment: I just asking is that possible because all third parties ios store use the same certificate and this certificate used origanly by app called tutuapp